# Transfer from smb to next cloud

Tags: smb, nextcloud

I have already smb network share set up. Every user has its own home folder that is shared. Now I want to switch to nextcloud as smb is quite slow when using vpn. Probably there is a way to fix it but as know nextcloud is faster and I'm not a network expert its just to big of a time waste. Now I want to keep my old smb structure and have the files shared from smb and from next cloud. But next cloud is not aware in case files are added from smb. How can tell next cloud to "scan" for new files? I'm guessing there is some command that I can run to check if new files are added.

Answer (score 0):

To enable this, you need to perform a full file scan with Nextcloud. As the folders get bigger, the file scans take more and more time, which is why an update trigger for newly added files is not worth it. The only other option is to run a cronjob once or twice a day at times when the cloud is least likely to be used.

To configure the cronjob for www-data the following changes have to be made:

1. type "sudo crontab -u www-data -e" in your terminal.
2. append the following line to trigger a file scan every day at 2am "0 2 * * * php "path_to_nextcloud"/occ files:scan --all".

Now all files in the data directory of Nextcloud will be scanned every day at 2am.

If you are not familiar with setting up a cronjob, use this site https://crontab.guru/